# Unable to call static method supplyAsync of class CompletableFuture on object of the same class! CompletableFuture c=new CompletableFutre; c fails

Tags: java, class, oop, static-methods, completable-future

In JAVA `CompletableFuture` is a class which contains a static method named `supplyAsync()` I can call this static method using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` pattern but I am unable to call the static method on object of the same class CompletableFuture.

Example:

```
CompletableFuture c = new CompletableFuture();
c.supplyAsync() //->doesnt work cant recognize the method supplyAsync!
```

My doubt is why cant we call static method on object of the same class?

I was expecting the `supplyAsync` method to be called on object of class `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Turns out IntellIJ code editor shows error while typing name of static method on object, (so as to recommend static method call from ClassName itself) but after writting the method name fully it does resolves the error!

Comment: `supplyAsync` requires a parameter. This has nothing to do with whether the method is static or not. And, by the way, since Java 9 you can use `c.completeAsync(…);` which will complete the instance referenced by `c`.

Answer (score 1):

> My doubt is why cant we call static method on object of the same class?

It's wrong. You can call static methods on objects like this,

```java
assert 3 == new CompletableFuture<>()
          .supplyAsync(() -> 1)
          .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 2), Integer::sum)
          .join();
```

But you shouldn't do this. Static methods are class-level methods, they should not be called on an object.